# Converting if else statement from javascript to php

Tags: php

In javascript my if else statement goes like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('input1').value;
var y = document.getElementById('input2').value;
if (x.length > 0 && y.length > 0) {
    //execute code
}
```

This is what I have soo far with php:

```
$varx = $_POST['input1'];
$vary = $_POST['input2'];
if () {
    //execute code
}
```

I have no idea how to convert x.length to a php variable. It would help me alot if someone knows how to do this.

I really want to have the if else statement in php so please don't come up with other solutions because I'll get even more confused. Because this code will be a part of a bigger project.

Comment: What about `strlen($varx)`?

Comment: Or, since the JS code only seems to check that both variables actually contain _some_ value you could simplify that to `if ($varx && $vary)` because of the way php will evaluate that expression. An empty string evaluates to `false` in php, a non empty string to `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below syntax for checking that variable is having value or not.

```
if (null != $varx && null != $vary) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped alot :)